# Tesseract 3.02 Unable to load DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, wrapper

I'm trying to create a simple OCR program using Tesseract [.Net wrapper for tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). I tried the sample project and it worked like a charm. 
The problem is, when I run my wpf project an `Unable to load DLL 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found.` error occurs Nothing to do with the code. I tried Dependency Walker ad it says that I am missing 3 DLLs. They seem to be Windows DLLs but they don't exist here: [Windows API Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh802935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Any idea what's going on?

**EDIT:**

I changed the target framework to 4 from 4.5, and there is nothing wrong with these DLLs now (the example project which is working perfectly is using NET Framework 4.0).

Now the problem is: `Failed to initialise Tesseract Engine`. Here is my simple code if that helps:

```
        try
        {
            using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                using (Pix img = Pix.LoadFromFile(filename))
                {
                    using (Tesseract.Page page = engine.Process(img))
                    {
                        text = page.GetText();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conv_text_tb.Text = text;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're copying all the tesseract-related DLLs to the bin/ folder? Also, you may want to include the names of the DLLs that you're having problems with.

Comment: Yes I do. The missing DLLs are `API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL` , `API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL` , `API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL` .

Comment: Did you try Googling the name of the DLLs? I found many threads on MSDN about Windows 8... removing them, for lack of a better word. There are other possibilities examined in the threads as well.

Comment: Yes I did. I changed the target framework to 4 from 4.5, and there is nothing wrong with these DLLs now (the example project which is working perfectly is using NET Framework 4.0). Now the problem is: `Failed to initialise Tesseract Engine.` I am updating the question with my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out the fix to that error. I changed the `Copy to Output Directory` property of the DLL files and the files located in the tessdata folder to `Copy Always`. It's working perfectly now.